# Solving inequality equation involving sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I have a function $f(k,\,i)$ involving binomial coefficients:
$$f(k,\,i)\,=\left(\begin{matrix}k+i \\ k\end{matrix}\right)=\frac{(k+i)!}{k!\,i!}$$
And the following sum over this function (expansion taken from answer by @user17762):
$$S(k,x)=\sum_{i=0}^xf(k,\,i)=\left(\begin{matrix}k+x+1 \\ k+1\end{matrix}\right)$$
Now, given some number $y\ge 0$, I need to find $x$ such that:
$$S(k,x-1)\le y<S(k,x)$$
Is it possible to solve this problem by coming up with some formula $g(k,y)$ such that
$$S(k,g(k,y)-1)\le y<S(k,g(k,y))$$

Let me add an example:

Given for $k=2$:
$$f(2,\,0\,\dots)=1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, \,\dots$$
$$S(2, 0\,\dots)=1,4,10,20,35,56,84,120,165,220,286, \,\dots$$
I need the following:
$$g(2,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}0 & \text{if} & y <1
\\ 1 & \text{if} & 1\le y <4
\\ 2 & \text{if} & 4\le y <10
\\ 3 & \text{if} & 10\le y <20
\\ 4 & \text{if} & 20\le y <35
\\ 5 & \text{if} & 35\le y <56
\\ 6 & \text{if} & 56\le y <84
\\ 7 & \text{if} & 84\le y <120
\\ 8 & \text{if} & 120\le y <165
\\ 9 & \text{if} & 165\le y <220
\\ 10 & \text{if} & 220\le y <286
\\ & \dots\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Here's something that comes close. For $g(3,y)$, multiply $y$ by $6$, take the cube root, take the integer part (the largest integer not exceeding the cube root), and subtract $1$. E.g., this gives $8$ for $122\le y<167$. I suspect that a better answer will be messy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The problem is, I need to be able to solve this for any value of k, so not just g(2,y) but also g(6, y), etc...

Comment: @GerryMyerson A close approximation would be acceptable for me, though, if it followed some predictable pattern as a function of k, e.g. if I could say something like "multiply y by 3k and take the (k+1)th root"...

Comment: For $g(k,y)$, multiply $y$ by $k!$, take the $k$th root, subtract $(k-1)/2$, and take the integer part. Well, try it, see how it goes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Some very quick empirical tests show an accuracy of around $\pm\,2$. Pretty good! :)

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^x \dbinom{k+i}{k} = \dbinom{k+x+1}{k+1}$$
I trust this should help you.

---

For smaller values of $k$, say for instance, $k=2$, we have
$$S(2,x)=\dbinom{k+x+1}{k+1} = \dbinom{x+3}3 = \dfrac{(x+3)(x+2)(x+1)}6$$ a polynomial of degree $3$. In general, $S(k,x)$ is a polynomial in degree $k+1$.

Comment: Definitely one step closer to the answer. Thank you. Is there an easy way to derive this equation? I checked it and it seems to work, but somehow I can't quite wrap my head around how you got this answer...

Comment: @MarkusA. See Problem 8 of [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2sq1hb3q80ighc/Exam1soln.pdf?dl=0), which provides both a combinatorial and algebraic proof.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @MarkusA. You get a polynomial of degree $k+1$ in $x$. This can be inverted to obtain $y$.

Comment: I've spent the last half hour trying to figure how to get this polynomial... Unfortunately it's been a while since I've done this sort of math. Do you have a pointer for me of how to proceed?

Comment: Wow... sorry... I really should have been able to figure that one out for myself... Been a long week... Having a computer solve that for $x$ in the general case is going to be a bit painful, though... I've found some stuff on gamma functions and their inverse. I'll keep reading on that to see if maybe that can give an answer more easily...

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but it seems to be too long for a comment.

In the same spirit as user17762's answer, we can "see" that we have polynomials and, as a result, $$S(k,x)=\frac 1{(k+1)!} \,\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}(x+i)$$ $$S(k,x-1)=\frac 1{(k+1)!} \,\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}(x+i-1)$$ So, in other words, for  given values of $k$ and $y$, you search for an integer $x$ such that $$\frac 1{(k+1)!} \,\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}(x+i-1)\leq y \lt \frac 1{(k+1)!} \,\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}(x+i)$$ Onr thing which may be could help is that $$\frac{S(k,x)}{S(k,x-1)}=1+\frac{k+1}x$$